# Gun Red Dot on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov

If one receives permission from their LOR to carry a gun on shabbos/yom tov for self defense, can the gun be equipped with a red-dot sight? The sight has a feature where the light is turned off after 10 minutes of not being moved, then it turns back on again when it is moved. Additionally, its settings can be changed so that the light is always on if necessary.

Comment: Is the red dot sight needed for the self defense?

Comment: Why not ask the same LOR?

Comment: @DoubleAA Regarding a gun equipped with a red-dot-sight, without the red dot, it would be extremely difficult/impossible to aim.

Comment: MrWhetherMan why are you asking if it is allowed a red dot sight? Is it how you've been trained to aim and therefore the best, or is it just the only one you own, or is it what you've been issued, or have you got another reason for not using another type of sight? And is there any particular issue with just leaving it on? How long does the battery last?

Comment: If you are allowed to carry the gun why would the feature that allows you to use it effectively be the one issue with doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Although I can't find a source that specifically mentions red dots, I found this essay on the OU website (https://outorah.org/p/21842/) written by physical science professor and semicha student Jacob Newman, who talks about guns on Shabbos in general. He cites that according to the Shulchan Aruch, *almost* all prohibitions are suspended when a risk to life exists. He also cites Gemara as saying that Shabbos can be violated even for a doubtful risk to life. He concludes that carrying a gun outside an eruv is subjective and one should obviously consult their LOR. It would perhaps make sense that this can be applied to a red dot as well, assuming the optic actually makes a significant difference in the shooter's ability to save lives. The essay also cites sources seeming to rule that guns are not muktze. I'm not sure that this can apply to red dots as well, so the pekuach nefesh issue is maybe the one to rely on, even in the instance that you're carrying inside an eruv.

Comment: Guns that have a red dot holographic sight are impossible to aim without the dot.

Comment: My understanding is you can remove the red dot and replace it with a metal plate and revert back to iron sights only. I think that is the alternative here.